# How to accept any date in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Actually i am working with AD and BS (date of my country).And i have defined data type as date in postgresql.Its 2075-02-30 today and suddenly postgresql is showing `date/time field value out of range: "2075-02-30"` because feb don't have this date. How to configure postgresql so that it will accept any date?

Comment: For those who don't know your country, could you explain AD and BS?

Comment: The Postgres (or better SQL standard) date range complies with the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar). I don't think there is a way to change that. In theory it would be possible to implement a new data type that uses a different calendar, but that is probably a really big development effort

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL's dates refer to real points in time based on the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar). You cannot use them to store dates from other calendars like February 30th.

One approach could be to keep this field as a simple `varchar`, possibly with a check constraint to enforce the format:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT date_ck CHECK (mydate ~* '^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$')
```

Comment: Shouldn't the regexp pattern be anchored on both ends?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe good point, thanks! Edited that in to my answer.